# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-avatar'

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am having a [MERN website](https://github.com/Samar-080301/MernCrudApp) with 2 folders in the Github repo, `client` and `backend`. When I am turning on the react server the output page is showing an error as

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/Student/Student.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-avatar' in '/MernCrudApp/client/src/components/Student'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

To reproduce this error please follow the following steps.

1. Clone the repo
2. Go into the `backend` folder and write `npm install` in the terminal and then `npm run start`, and then enter the `client` folder and repeat the commands respectively.

Comment: I am new to JavaScript so if there is any problem in explaining the issue, please notify me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'react-avatar' package in your `client`'s `package.json`.

`npm install react-package` in this folder and you should be good.